# How do I write an 'AND' condition in dust?

Tags: conditional-statements, dust.js

In my dust file, I have something like this :

```
<div class="{?cond1}hidden{/cond1}" role="alert">
{@localize key="warning" eng="Warning: Not allowed" /}
</div>
```

I would like to make the element hidden if cond1 AND cond2 = true. How do I add one more condition inline here ?

Comment: Read the section on using helpers: http://www.dustjs.com/guides/dust-helpers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, just wrap the classname in two conditions-- that's the equivalent of an AND.

```
<div class="{?cond1}{?cond2}hidden{/cond2}{/cond1}" role="alert">
  {@localize key="warning" eng="Warning: Not allowed" /}
</div>
```

Should your logic become more complicated, you can move the condition check out of the template and into your context. Simply write a function that does the evaluation and returns true or false:

```
{
  cond1: true,
  cond2: false,
  cond3: 'a',
  warningIsHidden: function(chunk, context) {
    return context.get('cond1') === true &&
           context.get('cond2') === true &&
           context.get('cond3') !== 'b';
  }
}
```

Comment: What we can use for OR condition in same example?